# Erlang modules on different physical servers

Tags: erlang, distributed-computing, erlang-otp, mnesia

I have an OTP application with following structure: [image: diagram]

What needed:

1. Services(1,2,3) need to talk to each other.
2. Service1 on one physical server, service2 on other physical server, etc.
3. Mnesia database shared for all services.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably can just launch services with `rpc` followed by manual linking to reproduce the structure you specified...

But the structure itself looks wrong. The main problem is that your cluster end up being asymmetric with some *main* and *slave* nodes. However usually you just generate a single OTP release that is pushed to the every node, so while booting code executed is exactly the same, so all the services are started on every node.

- This provides you easier release
- More reliability on failover

So I would recommend change your architecture to support this way of working. I assume you basically want every service being ran on the single node with load balanced. So you can try to find a framework that will do exactly that for you.

For example you may look into [riak_core](http://www.erlang-factory.com/upload/presentations/294/MasterlessDistributedComputingwithRiakCore-RKlophaus.pdf) to build distributed applications

Comment: i know i can run same app on multiple nodes, but one of services doing a lot of math work through NIF, thats why i need to deploy that service on dedicated server

Comment: This doesn't mean you do not have the same code on the every server, just you have a bit more complicated logic for determining what service starts what server, but I belive it still should not be supervised over the network